# Create simple array from column of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

if I have a multidimensional array containing data from certain mysql table, such as:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 5255071 [id] => 5255071 [1] => 2013-02-28 20:40:48 [sent] => 2013-02-28 20:40:48 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 5253758 [id] => 5253758 [1] => 2010-11-16 12:56:39 [sent] => 2010-11-16 12:56:39 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 5253517 [id] => 5253517 [1] => 2010-11-16 12:43:57 [sent] => 2010-11-16 12:43:57 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 5252348 [id] => 5252348 [1] => 2010-11-16 11:19:35 [sent] => 2010-11-16 11:19:35 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 5252343 [id] => 5252343 [1] => 2010-11-16 11:19:01 [sent] => 2010-11-16 11:19:01 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 5252254 [id] => 5252254 [1] => 2010-11-16 11:11:26 [sent] => 2010-11-16 11:11:26 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 5251390 [id] => 5251390 [1] => 2010-11-16 09:16:57 [sent] => 2010-11-16 09:16:57 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 5249381 [id] => 5249381 [1] => 2010-11-16 03:01:32 [sent] => 2010-11-16 03:01:32 ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 5249086 [id] => 5249086 [1] => 2010-11-16 02:47:30 [sent] => 2010-11-16 02:47:30 ) [9] => Array ( [0] => 5247987 [id] => 5247987 [1] => 2010-11-16 01:59:34 [sent] => 2010-11-16 01:59:34 ) [10] => Array ( [0] => 5247325 [id] => 5247325 [1] => 2010-11-16 01:33:12 [sent] => 2010-11-16 01:33:12 ) )
```

Is there a way to create a new single array containing only the 'id' values? this is:

```
array(5255071, 5253758, 5253517, 5252348, ...)
```

The idea is to avoid using a foreach loop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a foreach loop when this is exactly the kind of thing it is used for...

Comment: your array doesn't make any sense. the end result would be something like `$array['id'] = 103; $array['text'] = 'blah';` - you can't have multiple elements in the same key.

Comment: Could you show us the result of var_dump() of your array?

Comment: I don't think this is multidimensional array. It may be just array of associative arrays. Please show us your source array in some other way. Please print that array like this: `print_r($array);` and paste it.

Comment: Sorry, it is an array of associative arrays, yes, because it's the result from the MySQl query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for this:

```
function extractId ($array) { return $array['id']; }
$targetArray = array_map($sourceArray, "extractId");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = array_values($array['id']);
```

see: [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: This assumes the array structure is like `array('id' => array(...))` while apparently it is `array(array('id' => ...), array('id' => ...))`.

Comment: Is it? It's hard to tell from this notation. Wish we'd see an actual array instead of playing a guessing game :/

Comment: Well...looks like it to me anyway. Becaue it says `array` not `$array`...but you are right...my guess is as good as yours. ;)

Comment: This is not valid for an array of associative arrays, but thanks anyway. I want to avoid foreach because I must use native php functions whenever possible to avoid overloading the server, the array might be very large sometimes.